# What is the appropriate html tag to prevent search engines from displaying a website's body in the search results?

Tags: html, seo, meta-tags

I have a website that's indexed on Google. However because my description is so short, the contents in the body are displayed after the ellipsis `...` like so...

```
title for www.mysite.com
www.mysite.com
Brief description ... some body contents
```

Here's some sample html used in my website

```
<meta name="description" content="Brief description" />
<body>some body contents</body>
```

How can I make sure search engines only display the brief description inside the above tag, instead of displaying information in the body as well?

Comment: you could instruct it to not show a snippet by: <meta name="googlebot" content="nosnippet"> .. which could be enough as your brief description (less than 160 characters I take it) is unlikely to be valuable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such short descriptions would hardly fulfil Google's desire to provide informative/accurate snippets:

> "Google will sometimes use the meta description of a page in search
>   results snippets, if we think it gives users a more accurate
>   description than would be possible purely from the on-page content." -
>   http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35624

SEOMoz has a much more expansive review on how to avoid Google's overwriting of them: http://www.seomoz.org/blog/why-wont-google-use-my-meta-description

So the short answer is that you can't "make" search engines display your "weak" description, but you can block them altogether [as per @kabaros's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002840/what-is-the-appropriate-html-tag-to-prevent-search-engines-from-displaying-a-web#comment17642626_13002840)...